# Global variable before and after `end`

Tags: ruby

I am parsing a PDF file online in order to extract a text. The 2 completes codes:

First

```
require 'open-uri'
require "net/http"
require 'pdf/reader'

module OpenSSL
  module SSL
    remove_const :VERIFY_PEER
  end
end

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

io = open('https://www.mtholyoke.edu/sites/default/files/registrar/bulletin/docs/dept_econ.pdf')
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)

reader.pages.each do |page|
  iso = page.text
  $var = iso.scan(/Economics[\s\S]*Overview/)
  p $var
end
```

Second

```
require 'open-uri'
require "net/http"
require 'pdf/reader'

module OpenSSL
  module SSL
    remove_const :VERIFY_PEER
  end
end

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

io =  open('https://www.mtholyoke.edu/sites/default/files/registrar/bulletin/docs/dept_econ.pdf')
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)

reader.pages.each do |page|
  iso = page.text
  $var = iso.scan(/Economics[\s\S]*Overview/)
end

p $var
```

It appears that when I use `p $var` after `end`, I have truncated the result unlike the first code. Why does putting `p $var` after `end` give a different result from putting it before?

In my web app, I do need to do put it after the `end` and have the same result as the first code. How can I do so?

Comment: In the first example you print the value after each page. In the second you keep resetting it for each page. Maybe you want to `map` and get all the `scan` results?

Comment: yes, that's absolutely my point (getting all the results), could you help me with this ? many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tmp = reader.pages.map { |p| p.text.scan(/Economics[\s\S]*Overview/) }
```

`tmp` now contains a collection of all the `scan` results.

```
puts tmp.join("\n")
```

Will print them all out with newlines between each match.

Although won't that just print a wad of "Economics Overview"?

If you want to collect the pages themselves it's different code.

Comment: fits completely with my need, and saved my life, many thanks !